# In Ezekiel 44:19 is the concern with not sanctifying the people or with not soiling their holy garments?

Tags: ezekiel, symbolism

> Complete Jewish Bible
> Ezekiel 44:19
> But when they go out into the Outer Court, into the Outer Court to the people, they shall put off their garments wherein they minister and place them in chambers belonging to the Sanctuary and clothe themselves with other garments, **and they shall not sanctify the people with their garments.**

from Rashi's commentary:

> *and they shall not sanctify the people*: [Heb. וְלֹא יְקַדְשׁוּ אֶתהָעָם, lit. they shall not sanctify the people.] Jonathan renders: and they shall not mingle with the people in their garments, [i.e.,] they shall not touch the people with their holy garments, for ordinary garments are not ritually clean as regards [contaminating] holy garments.
>
> 44:19  וּבְצֵאתָם אֶל־הֶחָצֵר הַחִיצֹונָה אֶל־הֶחָצֵר הַחִיצֹונָה אֶל־הָעָם יִפְשְׁטוּ אֶת־בִּגְדֵיהֶם אֲשֶׁר־הֵמָּה מְשָׁרְתִם בָּם וְהִנִּיחוּ אֹותָם בְּלִֽשְׁכֹת הַקֹּדֶשׁ וְלָֽבְשׁוּ בְּגָדִים אֲחֵרִים וְלֹֽא־יְקַדְּשׁוּ אֶת־הָעָם בְּבִגְדֵיהֶֽם׃
>
> 44:19  καὶ ἐν τῷ ἐκπορεύεσθαι αὐτοὺς εἰς τὴν αὐλὴν τὴν ἐξωτέραν πρὸς τὸν λαὸν ἐκδύσονται τὰς στολὰς αὐτῶν ἐν αἷς αὐτοὶ λειτουργοῦσιν ἐν αὐταῗς καὶ θήσουσιν αὐτὰς ἐν ταῗς ἐξέδραις τῶν ἁγίων καὶ ἐνδύσονται στολὰς ἑτέρας καὶ **οὐ μὴ ἁγιάσωσιν** τὸν λαὸν ἐν ταῗς στολαῗς αὐτῶν

Is the idea that the priests should avoid sanctifying the people or that they should avoid defiling their holy garments?

Answer (score 1):

### The Answer given through the Prophet Haggai

**Haggai 2:12-13 NKJV**

> 12 “If one carries holy meat in the fold of his garment, and with the edge he touches bread or stew, wine or oil, or any food, will it become holy?” ’ ”
>
> Then the priests answered and said, “No.”
>
> 13 And Haggai said, “If one who is unclean because of a dead body touches any of these, will it be unclean?”
>
> So the priests answered and said, “It shall be unclean.”

### Conclusion

While sanctifying the people, they keep the garments that they ministered in clean.